# If there exists a sequence of integers $a_0,a_1,\ldots$ such that $a_n=\frac{a_{n-1}+n^k}{n}, \quad \forall n \ge 1$, then $3 \mid (k-2)$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, logic

Let $k$ be a positive integer. Show that if there exists a sequence of integers
$a_0,a_1,\ldots$ such that
$$a_n=\frac{a_{n-1}+n^k}{n}, \quad \forall n \ge 1,$$
then $3 \mid (k-2)$.

**ATTEMPT:**

I have tried for $k=2$ and found a sequence of integers $(a_n)$ with $a_n=n+1$ for any nonnegative integer $n$ that satisfied the reccurence relation and implies $3 \mid k-2$.

Let there be a sequence $a_0,a_1,a_2,\ldots$ such that
$$a_n=\frac{a_{n-1}+n^k}{n}, \quad \forall n \ge 1.$$
Suppose for the contrary that $3 \nmid k-2$. It means that $k=3t$ or $k=3t+1$, for some positive integer $t$.

**CLAIM:** $a_n = \frac{a_0+1+2^k+2\cdot 3^k+ \cdots + (n-1)!n^k}{n!}$ for any integer $n \ge 1$.

**PROOF OF CLAIM:** Easy back substitution to $a_n. \quad \Box$

Now, by the claim, there are $5$ cases that should be considered on $a_0$.
First, let's consider the case when $k=3t$, for some positive integer $t$.

1. $a_0>0$ and $a_0$ is even.

In this case, let $a_0=2s$ for some positive integer $s$. Consider $n=2$. Then
$$a_2 = \frac{a_0+1+2^k}{2!}=\frac{2s+1+2^{3t}}{2},$$
which is, clearly, not an integer, a **contradiction** with assumption that $a_2$ is an integer which is in the sequence of integer $a_0,a_1,a_2,\ldots$.

2. $a_0>0$ and $a_0$ is odd.

Let $a_0=2m+1$ for some nonnegative integer $m$. Notice that
$$a_3=\frac{2m+2+2^{3t}+2\cdot 3^{t}}{6}.$$
I got stucked here. How to conclude that $a_3$ is not being in the sequence of integers?

3. $a_0<0$ and $a_0$ is even.
4. $a_0<0$ and $a_0$ is odd.
5. $a_0=0$.

Comment: Why downvote? ${}$

Comment: Maybe start by trying to find at least one choice of $a_0$ and $k$ for which you can prove the sequence in question will always be integers. Next step should be more clear after that

Comment: Also, because math.stackexchange has a problem with students looking for free homework answers, it's common ettiquette to also write up a description of your current attempts on the problem in question. For example, if you've solved a problem similar to this one, maybe describe the method you used to solve the similar problem and what happened when you applied it to this problem.

Comment: @ChrisWolird OK, thanks a lot, Sir. But, I want first to know, is the statement correct?

Comment: I have no idea. Best of luck to you

Comment: Okay, sir. Thank you..

Comment: @ChrisWolird Could you see my answer above sir?

Answer (score 1):

**Some hints**: (Not a full answer)

If this is a series of integers, and the RHS is $(a_{n-1} + n^k)/n$, what must $a_{n-1}$ be divisible by? (Except in edge cases, which I'm sure exist.)

Consider trying out the simplest cases that are predicted to work or not work: if $3\mid k-2$, then $k=1$ ought to fail, and $k=2$ ought to succeed. Note though that we don't know for sure what $a_0, a_1$ are.

Try some easy values of $a_0$ and see if you can find a pattern, then use that pattern to figure out how to create a proof. This look like direct proof or contradiction are the best bets.

---

All right, let's see if I can give a full answer. First, let's be absolutely clear about what we're trying to prove. Calling a sequence fitting this recursion $A_k$, we want:

$$\exists A_k \implies 3 \mid k-2 \implies k \equiv 2 \pmod 3$$

Note the lack of a reverse implication. As formulated, in fact, it would be sufficient to prove that *no* such sequence exists. We don't have to find a sequence for all $k \equiv 2 \pmod 3$ because nothing says *every* such value generates a sequence.

Now, the reality is this: exactly one infinite sequence exists that fits these parameters, and that sequence has $k = 2, a_0 = 1$. And you might have seen this sequence before: its first ten terms are $(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)$.

With this in mind, let's see if we can prove what we actually want to prove.

---

Let's rewrite the recurrence slightly:

$$a_n = \frac{a_{n-1}}{n} + n^{k-1}$$

There are two takeaways from this:

1. First, $a_1 = a_0 +1$ no matter what $k$ is.
2. Second, it's clear that $a_n \in \mathbb{Z} \iff n \mid a_{n-1}$.

Therefore in order for the sequence $A$ to exist, there must be another sequence of integers $B = (b_0, b_1, b_2, \cdots)$ such that $A = (b_0, 2b_1, 3b_2, \cdots nb_{n-1}, (n+1)b_n \cdots)$. Sequence $B$ is just the quotients of the members of sequence $A$ with increasing $n$.

But we just said $a_1 = a_0 + 1$, which implies $2b_1 = b_0 + 1$

We can replace $A$ completely, and rewrite the recurrence as:

$$(n+1)b_n = \frac{nb_{n-1}}{n} + n^{k-1} = b_{n-1} + n^{k-1}$$

$$b_n = \frac{n^{k-1} + b_{n-1}}{n+1}$$

With the kicker that $b_n$ is an integer, so $n+1 \mid n^{k-1} + b_{n-1}$. And that has to be true for *every* value of $b_n$. How can we guarantee that?

Well, one obvious way is if $k-1 = 1$ and $b_{n-1}=1$. Then we just have $(n+1)/(n+1) = 1 = b_n$, so $b_n = 1$ for all $n$. This, of course, is the sequence described earlier.

OK, but can we guarantee that condition any other way? No, we can't. Let's take that last equality and make it a bit more generic:

$$t = \frac{n^r + s}{n+1}$$

This is now a polynomial division--we need $n+1$ to be a *factor* of $n^r+s$. But the set of values of $r,s$ for which $n^r + s$ can even be factored is... tiny. If $r$ is even, there's no factorization at all in the integers. If $r$ is odd, $n^r + s$ can be factored iff $s = q^r$. That factorization is:

$$n^{r} + q^{r} = (n+q)(n^{r-1} - n^{r-2}q + n^{r-3}q^2 - \cdots + q^{r-1})$$

Note the lack of an $n+1$ factor unless $s = q = 1$. But now consider the case where we have $t = (n^3 + 1)/(n+1)$. This factorizes, and $t = n^2 - n + 1$. But then $b_{n-1} = 1 \implies b_n = n^2 - n + 1 \ne 1$. So in the next recursion, there's no factorization available, and we are back to the original problem. This holds in parallel fashion for higher odd exponents.

Therefore we conclude that the *only* values for which this sequence contains only integers is the instance with $a_0 = 1, k=2$. Hence the one sequence that does exist has $3 \mid k-2$, and we've proven the original proposition.

Looking through this, I could have formalized better, but there's a lot of explanation throughout. Hopefully you can follow the logic; feel free to ask questions (and of course others, feel free to point out holes).

Comment: Note that the existence is dependent on the divisibility but not vice versa. It may be that only one series works--or even that none do, though that seems unlikely when posing a problem like this. Your focus probably is on the cases that *don't* work and why.

Comment: Thanks sir. But, could you see about my answer just now please?

Comment: @PitikKepit I'll add some more. I'll ask, though: have you happened to plug in easy values of $a_0$ yet for $k=1$ and $k=2$? You will definitely find something useful in there.

Comment: Many thanks, Sir. Yes, I have. I have tried $k=2$ and found the fact that $a_n=n+1$ for any nonnegative integer $n$ satisfied the reccurence relation in the problem. What about my approach, especially for the second case? How to conclude that $a_3$ is not divided by $3$?

Comment: @PitikKepit Check out my answer above, I added a full proof. Your approach, I think, won't get you to a proof.